# How to display address string from companies house API?

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

How would I display the address string from the companies house api documentation because at the moment a 'nan' message occurs in that column?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
company_number = row["Company_Number"]
ch_profile = ch_api.get_company_profile(company_number)
df.at[index, "Company_Name"] = ch_profile.get("company_name", None)
df.at[index, "address"] = ch_profile.get("address_line_1", None)

print(f"Number: {row['Company_Number']} | Name: {df.at[index,'Company_Name']} | Test: {df.at[index,'address']}")
```

Number: 09628959 | Name: PLANTING PROMISE LTD | Test: **nan**

Using the CHR: https://developer.company-information.service.gov.uk/api/docs/search-overview/CompanySearch-resource.html

Comment: Not familiar with the api, but looks like something is getting cast to a float where it shoudn't (NaN being Not a Number).

Comment: How would you fix the float if that maybe the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have queried the API url GET https://api.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/09628959

The Address will be available in 'registered_office_address' in the JSON

Full JSON response below:

```
{
    "registered_office_address": {
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "postal_code": "N1 2HW",
        "address_line_1": "34 Alwyne Road",
        "locality": "London"
    },
    "company_status": "active",
    "jurisdiction": "england-wales",
    "has_insolvency_history": false,
    "has_charges": false,
    "etag": "4de7ba79d9199cf0145bf05d8bcd89f79917caba",
    "type": "private-limited-guarant-nsc",
    "accounts": {
        "next_due": "2021-12-31",
        "next_made_up_to": "2021-03-31",
        "last_accounts": {
            "made_up_to": "2020-03-31",
            "period_start_on": "2019-04-01",
            "period_end_on": "2020-03-31",
            "type": "dormant"
        },
        "accounting_reference_date": {
            "month": "03",
            "day": "31"
        },
        "next_accounts": {
            "overdue": false,
            "period_start_on": "2020-04-01",
            "period_end_on": "2021-03-31",
            "due_on": "2021-12-31"
        },
        "overdue": false
    },
    "date_of_creation": "2015-06-08",
    "company_number": "09628959",
    "undeliverable_registered_office_address": false,
    "company_name": "PLANTING PROMISE LTD",
    "sic_codes": [
        "85200"
    ],
    "confirmation_statement": {
        "last_made_up_to": "2020-06-08",
        "next_made_up_to": "2021-06-08",
        "next_due": "2021-06-22",
        "overdue": true
    },
    "links": {
        "self": "/company/09628959",
        "filing_history": "/company/09628959/filing-history",
        "officers": "/company/09628959/officers",
        "persons_with_significant_control": "/company/09628959/persons-with-significant-control"
    },
    "registered_office_is_in_dispute": false,
    "has_super_secure_pscs": false,
    "can_file": true
}
```